# how to sort message and paging throught javamail imap

Tags: sorting, jakarta-mail, imap, paging

I want to get mail messages sort by date and paging.I use javamail imap.Is it has api to do that sort in server not in client?
I found roundcubemail can do this.
Any suggestion?thank advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the server supports the IMAP SORT extension.  If it does, you can use the [IMAPFolder.getSortedMessages](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getSortedMessages%28com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm%5B%5D%29) method to get the Message objects sorted appropriately.  You can then fetch the data for the messages in whatever groups/pages you like.

Comment: thanks.And how to know ther server suports imap sort extension or not?

Comment: You can use the [IMAPStore.hasCapability](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore.html#hasCapability(java.lang.String)) method.